# How to make the web page height to fit screen height

Tags: html, css

I need to make my web page height to fit the height of the screen size without scrolling.

HTML

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="main">
        <div id="content">

        </div>
        <div id="footer">

        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

CSS

```css
#content{ background-color:#F3F3F3; margin:auto;width:70%;height:700px;}
#footer{width:100%;background-color:#666666;height:200px;}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make div 100% height of browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A quick, non-elegant but working standalone solution with inline CSS and no jQuery requirements. AFAIK it works from IE9 too.

```
<body style="overflow:hidden; margin:0">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="main" style="background-color:red">
            <div id="content">

            </div>
            <div id="footer">

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script language="javascript">
        function autoResizeDiv()
        {
            document.getElementById('main').style.height = window.innerHeight +'px';
        }
        window.onresize = autoResizeDiv;
        autoResizeDiv();
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 25):

Fixed positioning will do what you need:

```
#main
{         
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 25):

As another guy described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window), all you need to do is add

```
height: 100vh;
```

to the style of whatever you need to fill the screen

Answer (score 5):

Don't give exact heights, but relative ones, adding up to 100%. For example:

```
  #content {height: 80%;}
  #footer {height: 20%;}
```

Add in

```
 html, body {height: 100%;}
```

Comment: Where does the absolute height come from. 100% of 0 is 0. How do you tell it what 100% is to begin with?

Comment: 100% is the full (current) size of the viewport. So you don't tell it, the browser actually determines the value of 100% by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#content{ background-color:#F3F3F3; margin:auto;width:70%;height:77%;}
#footer{width:100%;background-color:#666666;height:22%;}
```

(77% and 22% roughly preserves the proportions of `content` and `footer` and should not cause scrolling)

Answer (score 0):

you can use css to set the body tag to these settings:

```
body
{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using this, replace your class "home" with your own

```
(function ($) {
    $(function(){"use strict";
        $('.home').css({'height':($(window).height())+'px'});
        $(window).resize(function(){
        $('.home').css({'height':($(window).height())+'px'});
        });
    });
  
  })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you override the original styling by adding important.

```
height: 100vh !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used a CSS solution that has proved flexible.

You need choose one element to be the one that is full height. It also needs to be a parent to every content block. This can be the `<body>` element or anywhere in the DOM.

Additionally, you must designate one child to grow to make up whatever space is needed to stretch to fill the screen.

```css
.content-parent {
  min-height: 100vh;  /* Forces to always fill the screen vertically... */
  min-height: -webkit-fill-available;  /* ...except on mobile, when you want to stay within the chrome */
  display: flex;  /* Enable content to stretch... */
  flex-direction: column;  /* ...vertically */
}

.filler-child {
  flex-grow: 1;  /* Designates this element to stretch to fill */
}
```

Example HTML:

```html
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="hero">...</div>
      <div class="content filler-child">...</div>
      <div class="footer">...</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```