# how to fit the webpage exactly the screen size without scrolling?

Tags: html, css

I am new to css and I am finding some difficulty in setting my webpage to fit exactly the screen size but it doesn't fit and a scroll bar occurs. I have tried all the ways mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868474/how-to-make-the-web-page-height-to-fit-screen-height) But none of them works. My web page looks more or less like [this](http://www.rightfunds.com). When i used

```
html{
height: 100vh;
}

body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: gothambook;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    }
```

The scroll bar didn't occur but the content went below the screen and was not visible

Comment: `{max-width: 100vw; max-height: 100vh;}`

Comment: No it didn't work.

Answer (score 22):

```
html {}
body {
    height: 95vh;
}
```

vh stands for View Height and so 97vh is 97% the View/Browser's height.

https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/

For some reason 100vh makes it scroll a little.

Comment: 100vh makes it scroll due to margin and paddings of body tag.

Comment: That makes sense. Feel free to just edit my response.

Comment: This is not an appropriate solution. You shouldn't have to settle for setting the height to `95vh`; you need to figure out what is causing the extra scrolling and fix that.

Comment: I know this is 5 years old, but I wanted to tack on that it helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can fix this problem by changing both height and width to 100%. In your code, you have written height as 100vh.

```
html,
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

after changing them both to 100% you might still be able to scroll but you can fix that by adding this:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

In general for fixing this type of problem for any project this setup I think will always work:

```
html,
body{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

height: 100vh is not good idea to give it full screen.

**Try `min-height: 100%`**

Comment: may I ask also Why?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to completely disable the scroll then you can replace your styles with only this

```
html {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: this removes the scroll bar and pushes the content above the view port and make it not visible.

Comment: can you provide a codepen or jsfiddle with an example?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yrcgwsm7/ , The image links are not available since it was linked local.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Target both `html` and `body` and set both their `width` and `height` to `100%`.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: It didn't work and here s the fiddle have a look at it https://jsfiddle.net/yrcgwsm7/

Comment: @NaveenKumar I am not getting a scrollbar unless I make the view port around 200px tall.

Comment: yes that's another issue , if the view port size become less(more like mob version) the size fits in. But when the view port size increases to normal laptop size the scroll bar occurs

Comment: @NaveenKumar so what exactly are you trying to do? The code I posted will set the html/body element to fill the entire available area. If you want to fit your content that's an entirely different question. If you don't want a scrollbar use `overflow: hidden;` or, set `max-width: 100%;` on whatever your containing element is so it can never extend past the available space.

Comment: I am sorry for confusing , I want my content to fit in screen totally (without scroll bar), If i use overflow hidden and max-width:100%. Scroll bar disappears and some of my content also goes below the view port and not visible.

Comment: @NaveenKumar at a certain point your content will disappear. You can't fit 300px of content into a 100px container. There's no way to really get around that.

Comment: Funcionou para mim, obrigado

Answer (score 0):

If `body`'s direct child has top and bottom margin, it is going to make it scroll. So, we need to take that into account.

This works well for me:

```css
 body {
     height: calc(100vh - 4rem);
 }

 .content {
     max-width: 98.57rem;
     margin: 2rem auto;
     box-shadow: -1px 0px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
     min-height: 100%;
 }
```

```html
 <body>
    <div class="content">
            ....
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using flex can help, I have tried other things but it gets just too tricky. setting overflow: hidden can work but you would have to manually adjust the width and height again to match the current screen size, and if you keep adding children they wouldn't be visible

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

main {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 25px;
  border: solid 1px #84714f;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Fit screen size</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <main>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

After 2022 you can use new viewport units.

```css
height: 100dvh;
```

[State of CSS 2022 - Viewport Units](https://web.dev/blog/state-of-css-2022#viewport_units)